# Express для Node.js установился в Git

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, express

При глобальной установке express, на windows, он устанавливается в папку Git-а, соответственно не прописывается как переменная среды, как это исправить и почему это происходит?

Comment: Он и не должен никуда прописываться - даже в Linux и OSX. Просто устанавливаются как модуль Node.js, да и всё

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужно устанавливать express глобально? Зачем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, в файле npmrc был прописан свой путь.

Comment: @kff, да вроде это ответ.